# XPath 1.0: Select nodes with attribute matching attribute of context node

Tags: php, xpath, xml-parsing

I'm stuck processing XML data with [PHP's SimpleXMLIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmliterator.php).

While iterating over the nodes of one subtree (`/root/entries`) I try to gather related data from another subtree (`/root/entryvalues`) - matching the target nodes by an attribute of the *current node*.

Therefore I'd use [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) on the *current node* ("Context"; marked with a comment), trying to get those `entryvalue` nodes from (`/root/entryvalues`) that have an `entry` parent with the same `name` attribute value ("foo") as the *current node*.

```xml
<root>
    <entries>
        <entry name="foo"><!-- <- XPath starts here ("Context") -->
            <somedata>1234</somedata>
        </entry>
        <entry name="bar">
            <somedata>asdf</somedata>
        </entry>
        ...
    </entries>
    <somethingUnrelated />
    <entryvalues>
        <entry name="foo"><!-- <- want to select subnodes of this node -->
            <entryvalue name="foo1">
                <text>Foo 1</text>
            </entryvalue>
            ...
            <entryvalue name="foo-n">
                <text>Foo n</text>
            </entryvalue>
        </entry>
        <!-- no "bar" here -->
        <entry name="quux">
            <entryvalue name="quux1">
                <text>Quux 1</text>
            </entryvalue>
        </entry>
        ...
    </entryvalues>
</root>
```

A working XPath 2.0 expression could be something like `parent::*/following-sibling::entryvalues/entry[@name = current()[@name]]`, but I don't have XPath 2.0, so no `current()` function.

How to get those nodes?

---

For reference, here is the relevant PHP snippet:

```php
$xml = new \SimpleXMLIterator($xmldata);
foreach ($xml->xpath('//root/entries/entry') as $entry) {

    // ... extract some data from $entry

    $entryvalues = $entry->xpath('???');
    doSomething($entry, $entryvalues);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Damnit, found the obvious right after posting (in spite having banged my head for hours and searched the whole internet up and down):

Transport the `name` attribute value via PHP. Simple as that.

In my case:

```php
$template = 'parent::*/following-sibling::entryvalues/entry[@name = \'%s\']';

$xml = new \SimpleXMLIterator($xmldata);
foreach ($xml->xpath('//root/entries/entry') as $entry) {

    // ... extract some data from $entry
    $name = (string)$entry->attributes()['name'];

    $entryvalues = $entry->xpath(sprintf($template, $name));
    doSomething($entry, $entryvalues);
}
```

---

To my excuse, the actual code is a little more encapsulated, so I missed the option give `xpath()` more than a static string. (Still, I don't know how to do it with an XPath 1.0 expression alone, but I'm happy if it just works™.)